# logback logstash encoder Syslog header not set

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, logback, syslog, logstash-logback-encoder

I'm trying to log Java logs to Syslog in JSON format but I've found a strange issue where the Syslog header is not being set as expected.

I'm testing this on a Mac and using wireshark to grab the packets as they get sent to the UDP 514 port (via loopback interface)

My logback.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <conversionRule conversionWord="syslogStart" converterClass="ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.SyslogStartConverter"/>

  <appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
    <host>localhost</host>
    <port>514</port>
    <prefix class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%syslogStart{LOCAL5}</pattern>
      </layout>
    </prefix>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="stash"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

and when I look at the output of wireshark I only see the JSON being logged (no PRI header field given)

```
 [truncated]Syslog message: (unknown): {"@timestamp":"2016-03-22T12:13:37.270+11:00","@version":1,"message":"Started App in 4.327 seconds (JVM running for 4.92)","logger_name":"au.com.xxx.App","threa
```

If I switch to the standard logback Syslog appender (non JSON output)

```
...
  <appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>127.0.0.1</syslogHost>
    <Facility>LOCAL5</Facility>
    <SuffixPattern>%-5level MyApp %logger %msg</SuffixPattern>
  </appender>
...
```

I do see the correct header facility raw value <174> and parsed values LOCAL5.INFO in the wireshark packets

```
 Syslog message: LOCAL5.INFO: Mar 22 12:31:03 sbmelmac-06390.local INFO  App au.com.App Started App in 11.292 seconds (JVM running for 29.336)
```

The syslog header is required (in the syslog conf) to route the log messages to the correct files so without this I can't filter out log entries based on facility filters.

I'm using SpringBoot (1.2.7), (which uses logback 1.1.3), apache camel (2.16.1) and logstash-logback-encoder (4.6)

When I run in debug it looks like the SyslogStartConverter.convert method is never invoked.

Cheers
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching it looks like it's an issue with the wrapping LayoutWrappingEncoder part of the example.

When I use the latest SpringBoot version a logback configuration exception stops the app from starting up (previous versions did not stop the app from starting even though the exception was being raised).

```
Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@10d307f1 - A "ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder" object is not assignable to a "ch.qos.logback.core.Layout" variable.
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@10d307f1 - The class "ch.qos.logback.core.Layout" was loaded by 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@10d307f1 - [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93] whereas object of type 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@10d307f1 - "ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder" was loaded by [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93].
```

so if I remove the wrapping LayoutWrappingEncoder and use a Pattern implementation in the prefix, the code works and I see the correct Facility details in the syslog headers.

```
 <conversionRule conversionWord="syslogStart" converterClass="ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.SyslogStartConverter"/>
 <appender name="JSON_SYSLOG" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender">
    <host>127.0.0.1</host>
    <port>514</port>
    <prefix class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
       <pattern>%syslogStart{LOCAL5}</pattern>
    </prefix>
  </appender>
```

and the resulting wireshark packets have the Facility information (LOCAL5.INFO|ERROR)

```
 [truncated]Syslog message: LOCAL5.INFO: Mar 22 14:12:18 sbmelmac-06390.local {"@timestamp":"2016-03-22T14:12:18.494+11:00","@version":1,"message":"Started App in 4.597 seconds (JVM running for 5.18)","logger":"au.com.myapp.
```